Django 4.2 how to display deleted object failure in modeladmin page?
Code used to override the delete_queryset in the modeladmin:
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)        
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

   def really_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        '''
        # 1. Update the group-mailbox relation: `goto` values if mailbox(es) are deleted
        # 2. Sending a mail to the current user with CSV of mailboxes deleted
        # 3. Used domain space will reduce by the maxquota of mailbox
        '''
        response = None
        print('delete from mailbox queryset called')
        try:
            mbox_list = []
            failed_deletions = []
            print(queryset)
            for obj in queryset:
                mdomain = None
                # COMPLETE MAILBOX DELETION OF FOLDERS, DOVECOT ENTRY, ADMIN PANEL PERMANENTLY 
                api_delete_status = call_purge_mailbox_api(request,obj)
                response = api_delete_status
                print('response---------',response, response['status_code'])                
                if response['status_code'] == 200:
                    # Set the quota value after deletion of mailbox(es)
                    mdomain = Domain.objects.get(id=obj.domain.pk)
                    mdomain.quota -= obj.maxquota
                    mdomain.save()
                    mbox_list.append(obj.email) 
                    # Remove the user from the group mailing lists
                    # master_grp_list = GroupMailIds.objects.exclude(goto=None)
                    removed_from_groups :bool = remove_from_group_lists(obj.email,mbox_list)
                    print('mailbox deletion completed.....')
                    # TODO: List for sending a mail to the currently logged in user with CSV of
                    # mailboxes deleted
                else:
                    print('Failed to delete mailbox:', obj.email)
                    failed_deletions.append(obj.email)
 
            print(failed_deletions, len(failed_deletions))

            if mbox_list:  # Check if any mailboxes were successfully deleted
                self.message_user(request, f"Successfully deleted {len(mbox_list)} mailbox(es).",level='success')
            for email in failed_deletions:  # Display error message for each failed deletion
                self.message_user(request, f"Failed to delete {email}. Mailbox absent. Contact helpdesk.",level='error')
            if not mbox_list and not failed_deletions:  # Check if no deletions were attempted
                self.message_user(request, "No mailboxes were selected for deletion.",level='error')
                #return messages.error(request, "No mailboxes were selected for deletion.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.message_user(request, f"Failed to delete items: {str(e)}", level='error')
    really_delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected entries"

def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        try:
            if obj.id is None:
                # If the object's ID is None, it means the object doesn't exist
                self.message_user(request, "Failed to delete object. Object does not exist.", level='error')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)

            # Perform the deletion
            api_delete_status = call_purge_mailbox_api(request, obj)
            mbox_list = []
            if isinstance(api_delete_status, dict) and 'status_code' in api_delete_status:
                status_code = api_delete_status['status_code']
                if status_code == 200:
                    # If the deletion was successful, trigger response_delete
                    mdomain = Domain.objects.get(id=obj.domain.pk)
                    mdomain.quota -= obj.maxquota
                    mdomain.save()
                    mbox_list.append(obj)
                    # Remove the user from the group mailing lists
                    removed_from_groups :bool = remove_from_group_lists(obj.email,mbox_list)
                    print('mailbox deletion completed.....')
                    # TODO: List for sending a mail to the currently logged in user with CSV of
                    # mailboxes deleted
                else:
                    # If the deletion operation did not succeed, handle the failure
                    #self.message_user(request, f"Failed to delete mailbox {obj}. Contact Helpdesk", level='error')
                    return None
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle deletion failure
            self.message_user(request, f"Failed to delete {obj}. Error: {str(e)}", level='error')
            return None

def response_delete(self, request, obj_display, obj_id):
    obj = Mailbox.objects.filter(id=obj_id).first()
    if obj:
        self.message_user(request, f"Failed to delete mailbox {obj_display} Contact Helpdesk", level='error')
    else:
        print('no obj iddddddd present anymore, successfully deleted')
        self.message_user(request, f"Successfully deleted {obj_display}.", level='success')

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:myapp_mailbox_changelist'))

This code is displaying correctly for the delete_queryset on failure of deletion. But when we delete the mailbox object in the model admin page after confirm_delete(confirm_delete.html), the message displayed after returning to the listing page are:
Failed to delete mailbox yy@domain1.net. Contact Helpdesk
as well as
The mailbox “yy@domain1.net” was deleted successfully.
Failure is the expected result. But why does django also display successful deletion? How to hide this message in the modeladmin listing page for failed cases?
Deletion from queryset works as expected. Displays the failed message only

Just to clarify: do you mean the problem happens when you delete the mailbox from its change page (as opposed to from the changelist)?

yes, only the display of message is wrong though the behaviour is correct

The second user messages is created by ModelAdmin.response_delete, which is called in ModelAdmin._delete_view after your delete_model method has run:
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):

    def _delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context):
        ...
        if request.POST and not protected:  # The user has confirmed the deletion.
            if perms_needed:
                raise PermissionDenied
            obj_display = str(obj)
            attr = str(to_field) if to_field else self.opts.pk.attname
            obj_id = obj.serializable_value(attr)
            self.log_deletion(request, obj, obj_display)
            self.delete_model(request, obj)  # <--- first user message is created here

            return self.response_delete(request, obj_display, obj_id)  # <--- second message is created here
        ...

    def response_delete(self, request, obj_display, obj_id):
        ...
        self.message_user(
            request,
            _("The %(name)s “%(obj)s” was deleted successfully.")
            % {
                "name": self.opts.verbose_name,
                "obj": obj_display,
            },
            messages.SUCCESS,
        )
        ...

Also note that the redirect response that you are returning in delete_model is ignored here. Important is only the response returned by response_delete.
You don't see the second message if you are deleting from the changelist because that deletion is managed by the delete_selected action - not the delete_view inside the ModelAdmins.

tried overriding response_delete, still get the same 2 messages, Updating the code above

You're still calling ModelAdmin.response_delete in your overriden method (super().response_delete(...)), which means you will still get the second message.

Solved it myself. Updating the above code for others
